# asp.net calendar with dropdownlist years and months

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Hello i am using ajax calendar extender, and i want the years and the month can be selected with dropdownlist.

2 images attached, first with the existing and the second with the wanted result.
thanks.

[image: existing calendar]

[image: wanted calendar]

Comment: Use Jquery UI for that it will be very easy in any web application: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: this is not answering my question, thanks for trying.